# I can not connect view controller to code using windows keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I started to learn IOS development. I am going through a video tutorial. The instructor is connecting the Hello World to the code by pressing control and using the mouse, as you can see in the screenshot :

[image]

I have windows 7 machine. I rented a mac VM from xcodeclub. When I tried to press control and connect the viewcontroller to the code by dragging mouse as done by the instructor, it do not connect. I am using windows keyboard. So how to do this ?

Is any other way to do this ? Or I have to use some other key + mouse drag ?

Comment: You means ctrl + right click to drag ?

Comment: No, It's not working.

Comment: Ctrl + click == right click

Comment: Right click works fine, it opens a pop up.

Comment: @KristianFox : When I right click on Hello world and drag it to the code, it do not connect it.

Comment: It looks like your view controller is not setup correctly in the storyboard. You need to set its custom class to be CCViewController

Comment: The author was showing it can't be connected to the comments, In my case I am trying it to connect to code. There is that blue arrow in authors video but when I try to do it, no arrows are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix**. Try right clicking on the label and dragging from new referencing outlet.

Otherwise, check to see if your view controller is the correct class. Click on your storyboard file (probably called main.storyboard or something similar) and select the graphical representation of your view controller. Then, on the right hand side click on the small icon that is the 'identity inspector'. Make sure under custom class it displays UIView. If it doesn't, change it to UIView and try again.

If that doesn't work make sure you're dragging the blue line across the screen so that when you release it you are between the @interface and @end lines of code. Like this:

```
@interface
// drag it here...
@end
```

Comment: There is no blue line in my case.

Comment: If you right click on the label 'Hello World' what do you see?

Comment: A new pop up with Outlet collection, referencing outlets, referencing outlet collection.

Comment: If you look under 'Referencing Outlets' try dragging from the little circle next to 'New Referencing Outlet'. What happens then?

Comment: Its worked, Thank you. Can you modify your answer so I can select it as correct answer.